# Editing Style of UITableView - Add/Delete

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I added the following code in my **UITableViewController** subclass, it shows something like in the screen shot, which is like a radio button, can select/deselect it. Selected button does have red-colored tick symbol. What is the button meant for?

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete | UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert; 
}
```

[image: UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete | UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you have used is for selecting value/values from the list in the table view. But before you use this function you have to include two more functions in your viewController :

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You can use the selected value of the list somewhere else, may be in the next viewController.